# Inquiries about CONNECTED APP from Salesforce

Tags: integration, connected-apps

In a function currently under development, there is a problem both externally and during receiving.
As I write each problem, I would appreciate it if you could comment your ideas.

1. External server companies cannot use the Consumer Key and Secret issued by SFDC.
   (I was informed that the key and secret issued by the server company must be used according to the rules of the server company.)

2.Certification was possible through the current certification provider and named creditionals (progress with client creditional).

3. I want to receive data through SFDC's Connected App, but sfdc's Consumer Key and Secret cannot be modified.
4. Currently, alternatively, we are receiving through the site. However, there are many potential problems because the site will be charged additionally.

**In summary, I am curious about how to receive data through the Connected App using the Consumer Key and Secret issued by the external server.**

The image below is an image certified by named creditionals.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most of your assertions here are either incorrect or don't really make sense (given the words you've used). You need to focus on a single question at a time here. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started. [Searching for "integration" on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/search/learning?keywords=integration&sort=RELEVANCE&levels=beginner&levels=intermediate) would be a good starting point.